# socket.setdefaulttimeout interacting with M2Crypto connection

Tags: m2crypto

I'm making a secure SSL connection to a server using python and M2Crypto.  See code below.

```
from M2Crypto import SSL, m2,x509
from M2Crypto.m2xmlrpclib import Server, SSL_Tranport
ctx = SSL.Context()
m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privkey(ctx.ctx,myKey.pkey)
m2.ssl_ctx_use_x509(ctx.ctx,myCert.x509)
server = Server(serverUrl, SSL_Transport(ctx))
server.ping()
```

The above works fine.  If I try to change the default socket timeout by adding the following two lines at the beginning of the code, I get a protocol error.

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(40)
```

This is the error I receive:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/xmlrpclib.py", line 1096, in **call**
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/xmlrpclib.py", line 1383, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/m2xmlrpclib.py", line 68, in request
    headers
xmlrpclib.ProtocolError:

Why is the default socket timeout causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a patch that can fix this.  It is for Linux only.  See Bug 2341 --> https://bugzilla.osafoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2341

I have not tried the patch.  I will use a different work around. I set the socket timeout to None then run my M2Crypto code then set the socket timeout back to the value I need for the rest of my code.

```
origTimeout = socket.getdefaulttimeout()
socket.setdefaulttimeout(None)
# run M2Crypto code
socket.setdefaulttimeout(origTimeout)
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what the problem was and what the patch is (as a new issue at https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/new, please), so we can consider it for the current m2crypto, please? Thank you.